# Junit testing with code contracts

Tags: java, junit

So i have this method which creates an account:

```
private int balance;

@Requires("initialBalance > -1")
public Account(int initialBalance) {
    balance = initialBalance;
}
```

Notice the "@Requires("initialBalance > -1")" to stop an account being created with a negative balance.

I'm trying to run the following test to ensure an account with a negative balance isn't created:

```
@Test(expected=PreconditionError.class)
public void testAccountBad() {
    new Account(-1);
}
```

The code runs fine but the test fails even when stating the expected precondition error in the test.

Constructive help would be greatly appreciated, still finding my bearings in this area.

Comment: What _applies_ the @Required rule? I'm guessing that whatever is reponsible for applying that is not running in your test context. For example; some sort of 'AOP delegating to a validator' might be provided by an application container at runtime but that piece is not available when you invoke `new Account(-1)` from a JUnit test runner.

Comment: You tagged your question with `code-contracts`.  That tag refers to a .NET feature.  Are you using .NET?  If so, how does JUnit run in .NET?  Or are you using something else, such as [Contracts for Java](https://github.com/nhatminhle/cofoja)?  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Cofoja framework](https://github.com/nhatminhle/cofoja) for @Requires?

If yes, it uses "bytecode instrumentation to provide run-time checking".

To have working tests make sure:

> To execute code compiled with contract checking enabled, make sure the
>   generated files (additional .class and .contracts files) are in your
>   class path and enable the Cofoja JAR file as a Java agent.
>
> Or use the offline instrumenter, which lives in the PreMain class,
>   under the com.google.java.contract.core.agent package, and takes paths
>   to class files as command-line arguments.